# download file stored in hyperlink

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

I'm working on j2ee application. I want to point out to a URL and download a PDF file using java code.

I have access to go through the URL(https://myPlan.com/viewPlan/purchase/artifact/), by default it takes my domain credentials and again it wont ask to enter the credentials to open that webpage. I want to hit the URL, and on that webpage, it has a hyperlink "get the files in Zip" which when clicked zip file which contains the documents are downloaded.Please advice how can i achieve it. Does any one gone through the same scenario? I tried below code but ended up with exception.

Below is the exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL
```

java code used:

```
 try {
            System.setProperty("http.agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.29 Safari/537.36");
            url = new URL("https://myPlan.com/viewPlan/purchase/artifact/");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
        InputStream is =null;
        try {
            is = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Please suggest how to **hit the webpage and download the files which** gets downloaded when we click on the link "files in ZIp" using java code. Or can we achieve the same using ajax,jQuery or any other API related to java. Please adivice. Any suggestions or link stating examples would be very helpful. One more point to add is here i does not have any direct link to point the URL and start downloading the file.The URL mentioned above has the link "get the files in Zip" which when clicked the files were downloaded.

Comment: 403 means unauthorized request and between the URL gives 404 not found when click on it

Comment: Ya, can I know how to point to URL which logs in directly by taking domain username and password?

Comment: I don't know how this website authenticate but it may use access token associated with the URL

Comment: Can you provide any sample example links.Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL is the exception i'm facing. @user7790438